# Get date from ntp server using DOS batch script?

Tags: batch-file, dos, ntp

Maybe someone has an idea.  I want to ensure that the system has the right day / year within at least a couple of days before my script is run. Any ideas on how I can do that ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See this guide http://www.pool.ntp.org/en/use.html

> If you're using a recent Windows version, you can use the ntp client that is built into the system. As administrator enter
>
> `w32tm /config /syncfromflags:manual /manualpeerlist:0.pool.ntp.org,1.pool.ntp.org,2.pool.ntp.org,3.pool.ntp.org`
>
> at the command prompt. This will work on Windows 2003 and newer. If you use an older version of windows you can try
>
> `net time /setsntp:"0.pool.ntp.org 1.pool.ntp.org 2.pool.ntp.org"`
>
> The same can be achieved by, as administrator, right-clicking the clock in the taskbar, selecting 'Adjust Date/Time' and entering the server name in the 'Internet Time' tab.
>
> Meinberg made a port of the [ntp daemon for windows](http://www.meinberg.de/english/sw/ntp.htm).
>
> If your Windows system is part of a domain, you might not be able to independently update your computer time. For more information about setting the time on windows, see [How Windows Time Service Works](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc773013%28WS.10%29.aspx).

Also check out the `%date%` and `%time%` environment variables.

Comment: Thank you. Will have a look at this.

Comment: actually I just looked at this, I want to get the date from the servers NOT set it . So if the the system has the wrong date /time, I can echo that it's incorrect.

Comment: @MikeQ To clarify, you want to get the time from the NTP server and check it against the computer running the batch script?  Or you just want to get the time from a windows server?

Comment: I want to get the time from NTP server, then check it against the computer running the script.  If it is drastically off, quit the script or pop up with messaging warning the user of the issue.

Answer (score 3):

I have same problem. You can use that compare the local time with on off the ntp pool.

```
w32tm /stripchart /samples:1 /computer:es.pool.ntp.org /dataonly
```

I have a script that fails if the difference is bigger than 180 sec. I can expand it if you still need it.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This site is not your typical forum. Answers here should always be as complete as you can make them for the benefit of others that come along looking for answers. Thanks.

Comment: I ended up setting the locale to USA etc. with registry change, got the data in that format then changed it back.